# regex pattern not producing any output and cannot identify why it's not working

Tags: regex

I am trying to edit my regex pattern so it can complete this condition; a variable is assigned to an array element which index is either a numeric value, a variable, or an arithmetic expression.

For example, the strings `"a3a=7;"`, `"a = b;"`, `"a[i]=b[j];"`, `"a=z[2];"`, `"a=f*2;"`, `"a[5]=z+a;"`, `"a = z[i+7];"`, `"a = z[i+7]+11;"`​ are considered to be correct assignment statements (note that there is a semicolon at the end of each statement).

The strings `"a=6"`, `"a-=10;"`, `"a+=n;"`, `"d=#$&_h"`, `"a*=r;"`​ are considered to be incorrect.

However, I keep getting it wrong.

Here is the pattern at the moment `regex pattern("[A-Za-z]+(([A-Za-z0-9])*|(\\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\\])*)*\\s*\\=\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*(([\\+\\-\\*\\/]\\s*)*([A-Za-z0-9]\\s*)*|(\\s*\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])+\\s*)*;");`

`regex pattern("[A-Za-z]+(\\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\\])?\\s*=\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\s*[+\\-*/]\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\s*\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])?(\\s*([+\\-*/]\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\s*\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\]))*;");` tried this it but does not give any output.

Comment: Please show your code so we see what you've tried. Please also use code formatting in the code sections of your question.

Comment: You might want to head over to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to experiment with your regexes.

Comment: And use raw strings.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a parser, not a regex.